# convert hus and pes file to any types of images

Tags: c++, c, unix, file-conversion, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert a massive number of hus and pes files (embroidery files). I was able to do it using ImageMagick in centos but I encountered memory allocation errors and also it only works for pes files. Is there a script that can handle this for both file types?

I tryed in imageMagick with a lot of versions and a lot of files but I wasn't able to do it.

there are a couple of windows software that can do this, but it takes to much time to do it file by file.

Comment: Maybe [Embroidermodder](http://embroidermodder.github.io/features.html#anchorBatch) is what you're looking for. It is cross-platform and can do batch-conversions.

Comment: this could be exactly what I need but I can't find the command tool utility, I can download only the editor. Any tips?

Comment: I think you have to build it from source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to jpw I found a solution. Embroidermodder confers a conversion to svg that I can convert to png using convert. I had to build it from source but it worked very well.

Comment: Glad Embroidermodder helped, I thought about adding a direct output to PNG/JPG/GIF. It hasn't been requested actually but I am now considering adding it since you have a legitimate use case I can image others.

Comment: I ported over all the embroidermodder lib embroidery stuff and rewrote it all, and ended up having somebody genuinely request export to png, so I added that.